# How to solve the Missing Google could messaging file from exter in android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, android-2.2-froyo

I have downloaded a demo project of GSM services.

For using it, I need to install a file name Google could messaging but, it is missing from my SDK.

How can I add this file to my SDK?
New To Android

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCMS (Google Cloud Messaging Services), you need to build a library project which uses Play Services and import it into your work-space.

Generally:

1. Install the Android SDK from [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
2. Download and configure the Google Play services SDK, which includes the Google Maps Android API. You can see the setting up on [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Don't forget to add the required Google Play services settings in your application's manifest.

> When you add the Play Services library to your project, be sure to add it with resources, as described in Setup Google Play Services SDK. The key point is that you must reference the library. Simply adding .jar file to your project won't work. You must follow the directions for referencing a library, or your app won't be able to access the library's resources, and it won't run properly.

You can get the full instructions from [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).